# Pandas Memory Error when trying to fill NaNs with 0s

Tags: python, pandas, memory, fillna

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 10.0 GiB for an array with shape (80213, 16757) and data type float64

How can I avoid this error and allocate more memory? I am on Windows 11 with 16 GB of RAM

Comment: Maybe create or enlarge the swap file.

Comment: A broader question is why you need such a huge DataFrame all held in memory and whether whatever processing you want to do can be achieved in a less memory demanding way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For huge matrices, with most values equal to zero, use sparse matrices instead. (e.g., https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) this will not overwhelm your local RAM.